# Implementing text editing for comments

Tags: django, rich-text-editor

I am creating a website with Django and have some part where users can insert text that can be viewed by others. I now want to implement text formatting as an option for the user. For a number of reasons I want to try and create my own editor with its own tags, e.g. [strike] [/strike] and as such am looking for documentation regarding this topic. Does anyone know of any good resources regarding design patterns / techniques for these type of concepts.

I have been frantically searching but my problem is I don't know the generic name for this topic. I keep running into wysiwyg editors and markdown, which so far only provide me with information on implementing existing solutions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language may be good places to find terms - "markup language" is probably the phrase you want. On the other hand, as someone who's implemented their own custom lightweight markup language for a work project - if you can use an existing one that has libraries for parsing it already, I'd strongly recommend that over writing your own parser. :)

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for.